# Case with Sub Query Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am using this query to get the Sum and Count of Visits

```
SELECT 
  b.SiteID, 
  c.AreaName, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN VisitCode = 1 THEN 1 END) AS [PM],
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VisitCode = 1 THEN 1 END) AS [PMCount],
  SUM(CASE WHEN VisitCode = 2 THEN 1 END) AS [CM],
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VisitCode = 2 THEN 1 END) AS [CMCount],      
  SUM(CASE WHEN VisitCode = 1 THEN 1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN VisitCode = 2 THEN 1 END) AS [Total]
FROM (
  SELECT 
    a.SiteCode, 
    a.VisitCode,
    a.AreaCode,
    a.RequiredFuelFilled,
    a.RequiredVisitDate
  FROM tblFuelTroubleTickets a
  WHERE a.RequiredVisitDate BETWEEN '2023-03-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2023-03-15 23:59:59.999' 
) sales_data
PIVOT (
  SUM(RequiredFuelFilled)
  FOR VisitCode IN ([1], [2])
) AS PVTTABLE
INNER JOIN tblSites b
ON PVTTABLE.SiteCode = b.SiteCode
INNER JOIN tblAreas c
ON PVTTABLE.AreaCode = c.ID
GROUP BY b.SiteID, c.AreaName, b.SiteCode
ORDER BY [Total] DESC
```

I am getting an Error Invalid Column name 'VisitCode' but Col exists, seems like I am missing something.

```
  SUM(CASE WHEN VisitCode = 1 THEN 1 END) AS [PM],
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VisitCode = 1 THEN 1 END) AS [PMCount],
  SUM(CASE WHEN VisitCode = 2 THEN 1 END) AS [CM],
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VisitCode = 2 THEN 1 END) AS [CMCount],      
  SUM(CASE WHEN VisitCode = 1 THEN 1 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN VisitCode = 2 THEN 1 END) AS [Total]
```

Comment: `PIVOT` has taken the `VisitCode` and `RequiredFuelFilled` columns and pivoted them in to columns named `[1]` and `[2]`. You then use conditional aggregation *(`SUM(CASE)`)* to pivot *again*. You probably don't want the `PIVOT` at all. I suggest you run your query without the `GROUP BY` and with `SELECT *` to see what you're working with.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using PIVOT ***and*** conditional aggregation, but the PIVOT is removing the columns you're trying to use in the conditional aggregation.

I'm convinced you don't want PIVOT at all...

```
SELECT 
  s.SiteID, 
  a.AreaName, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN t.VisitCode = 1 THEN t.RequiredVisitDate END) AS [PM],
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t.VisitCode = 1 THEN 1 END) AS [PMCount],
  SUM(CASE WHEN t.VisitCode = 2 THEN t.RequiredVisitDate END) AS [CM],
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t.VisitCode = 2 THEN 1 END) AS [CMCount],      
  SUM(t.RequiredVisitDate) AS [Total]
FROM
  tblFuelTroubleTickets   AS t
INNER JOIN
  tblSites   AS s
    ON t.SiteCode = s.SiteCode
INNER JOIN
  tblAreas   AS a
    ON t.AreaCode = a.ID
WHERE
      t.RequiredVisitDate >= '2023-03-01' 
  AND t.RequiredVisitDate <  '2023-03-16'
GROUP BY
  s.SiteID, a.AreaName, s.SiteCode
ORDER BY
  [Total] DESC
```

I also removed your a, b, c aliases, and used letters that mean something, and improved the WHERE clause to be more robust.

Comment: Replacing t.RequiredVisitDate END with t.RequiredFuelFilled ELSE 0 END has done the Job